# dbDelta with the character ;

Tags: dbdelta

To manage database plugin update, I changed my code using `dbDelta`.

**old code**

```
myfunction(){
   ...
   $query_string = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} {$str_column_names} VALUES {$str_values}";

   $is_data_inserted = $wpdb->query( $query_string );

   if( !$is_data_inserted ){
       $message_error = sprintf( "impossible to insert the data %s for the table %s!",
       serialize( $data_item_attrs ),
            $table_name
        );
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        wp_error_log( $message_error, "Insert Data Error" );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**new code**

```
myfunction(){
   ...
   $query_string = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} {$str_column_names} VALUES {$str_values}";
   dbDelta( $query_string ); 
}
```

My problem is using `dbDelta` disturbs inserts containing the character ";".
It´s because in `dbDelta`, there is ";" as delimiter.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: please check this code : myfunction(){
   global $wpdb;
   $query_string = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} {$str_column_names} VALUES {$str_values}";
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $query_string ); 
}

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: Why are you trying to use `dbDelta` for inserting data? That's not what it's for. It's intended for creating and modifying tabes. To insert data use [`$wdb->insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/).

Comment: yes jacob is always right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens for this reason :

> The function `dbDelta` can receive as first parameter (`$queries`) an array or a string. If `$queries` is a string, `dbDelta` will make an array with ";" as delimiter.

**inside dbDelta**

```
if ( !is_array($queries) ) {
    $queries = explode( ';', $queries );
    $queries = array_filter( $queries );
}
```

So the solution is to make an array of queries instead of a string as a first parameter like this:

```
myFunction(){
    ...
    $query_string = array(
        0 => "INSERT INTO {$table_name} {$str_column_names} VALUES {$str_values}"
    );
    dbDelta( $query_string ); 
}
```

The answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062621/wordpress-dbdelta-function-fails-to-execute-my-query).